# Why SSRS PDF link is not clicking

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, msbi

I am working with the SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008. I want to integrate PDF link in a SSRS report. The PDF complete link is stored in database. When I open that link on file explorer and browser. The PDF file is opening, but when I run the report and click on PDF hyperlink it is not opening on browser. The steps for opening the PDF file on web browser which I have applied is mentioned below:

1. Right click on tablix column where the PDF link is set.
2. Go to the text box properties.
3. Go to the Action tab.
4. Select Go To URL option.
5. Go to the fx expression. Below is the expression

   ```
   ="javascript:void(window.open('" & REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!PATH.Value, "\", "/"), " ", "%20") & "','_blank'))"
   ```

`Fields!PATH.Value`: the `PATH` field contains the complete pdf file link. The PDF link is mentioned below.

file:///D:/Application/DocumentsFile/01002620sam00000112020511_112722_Release%20Note%20(abcdefg).pdf

When I open this link on file explorer and browser the file is opening. But it is not opening when I click on ssrs report hyperlink.

[Report View, Here you can see PDF hyperlink in "Attachment" column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKX3L.png)

I am expecting when I'll click on PDF link, The PDF file will be opening in web browser.